# How can I make a complex octopus merge?

Tags: git, merge

I just make 8 different suggestions off of the tip of master, and I want to make a commit that merges all of them together. I've done the merges by manually resolving merge conflicts one-by-one (and then squashed them together with `git merge --squash`), but now, when I try to make an octopus merge commit with `git merge -s ours branch1 branch2 branch3 etc`, it replies `Merge with strategy ours failed.` If I commit the squashed merges and *then* a multi-parent commit, the commit works, but I have a commit that does something, followed by an empty commit, and I don't want that. How do I combine the *merge content* commit with the *merge parent* commit?

Comment: For reference, here's the pull request where I used this: https://github.com/c9/open-in-c9-extension/pull/11

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It sounds like you have a tree with the right content, and now you want to create a commit with that content and the right parents.  I'm not entirely sure how you'd use git porcelains to make the commits you want, but as you've got the plumbing accessible to you, you may use that directly if you'd like.

If you've got all your files correctly merged and in your index, you can find out the hash of the tree using `git write-tree`:

```
$ git write-tree
4d5fcadc293a348e88f777dc0920f11e7d71441c
```

You can then create a commit with the right parents:

```
$ git commit-tree 4d5fcadc293a348e88f777dc0920f11e7d71441c -p branch1 -p branch2 ... -m "Dummy Message"
85e2a8f2f71816d17887caaf39e46225e47165a9
```

And update your branch to point at that new commit

```
$ git reset --hard 85e2a8f2f71816d17887caaf39e46225e47165a9
```

I usually create the commit with a dummy message then go back and use `git commit --amend` to fill it in later.

Comment: Oof. In the future, is there any cleaner way to do this? It seems like `-s ours` should be able to handle this, I can't figure out why it didn't.

Comment: It does seem that it should work, but I think git may be being conservative about not overwriting your local changes.  I've just had another idea, let me add a second answer...

Comment: This was the approach I ended up taking.

Comment: Thank you so much for this. I have been hacking my way around this for years. Excellent strategy.

Answer (score 3):

If you'd prefer not to use plumbing directly (and who could blame you?) then you may be able to rebase your problems away.

The trick here is that you have one commit with your actual changes in it, and a single parent, and another with no changes but multiple parents.  If you squash changes together, then the first commit's parents remain.

At the moment, your commits are in the wrong order to do a squash: the second commit, with its parents, would be lost.  But because that commit has no changes, it should be possible to re-order them so the squash will work.

If you're working on master, and origin/master points at the last commit before you started, then do `git rebase -i origin/master` which should give you two commits in an editor:

```
pick 12345 All changes here
pick 67890 Octopus merge
```

Move the second line up, then squash in the changes:

```
pick 67890 Octopus merge
squash 12345 All changes here
```

Save and exit, and I hope that works :).

Comment: That was one of the first things I tried. One, all the parents of 67890 will appear between 12345 and 67890 (and replaying them will replay the merge conflicts): two, trying to squash it (probably due to an error of some kind in the design of rebase) fails due to "-m" not being specified to `git cherry-pick` (regardless of whether or not `-m` is present in the arguments to `git rebase`).

Comment: I think I've had an insight into why this happens: `rebase` is fundamentally designed to *undo* merges, not *redo* them. It's pretty much designed around taking some commits that have been convoluted into a *tree* and rewriting them into a *line*.

Comment: As of today (git version 2.20.1), I found that this answer actually works (except for the rebasing hint, IIRC there wasn't _the_ single merge commit as I tried this) while the plumbing one doesn't (at least for me, with `git` just hanging and doing nothing).